# Функция декоратор или кастинг

Tags: javascript

Как мне сделать функцию обёртку, которая принимает строку, и возвращает новую строку с начальными заглавными символами?

**Ввод:** *"How can mirrors be real if our eyes aren't real"*

**Вывод:**     *"How Can Mirrors Be Real If Our Eyes Aren't Real"*

-- Уточненее
Да вы,  правы хотелось бы увидеть как можно написать функцию декоратор, которая оборачивает другую функцию, и в итоге получается строка в которой каждое слово с заглавной буквы. Это мне позволит изменять исходную функцию по своему усмотрению, а когда нужно вызвать декоратор на этой функции и получить каждое слово с заглавной буквы. Если я правильно понимаю. Поясните?

```js
var str = "How can mirrors be real if our eyes aren't real";
var arr = str.split(' ');

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  console.log(arr[i][0].toUpperCase() + str.slice(1));
}
```

Comment: а причем тут _Функция декоратор или кастинг_?

Comment: @Grundy мне для примера, никак не могу сообразить эту тему

Comment: Ну и что же не так с вашим кодом? Или мы должны сначала угадать вашу проблему, а потом уже давать ответ?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev что конкретно не понятно? в вопросе всё описал подробно. Ввод такой - How can mirrors be real if our eyes aren't real" . Вывод должен быть таким -  "How Can Mirrors Be Real If Our Eyes Aren't Real" . Хочу сделать с помощью функции декоратора. Мой код выдаёт кашу , прошу помощи у сообщества.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Полагаю, подобная функция также должна "нормализовать" хвост.

```js
function repl() {
  return this
    .replace(/[^\s-]+/g, function(txt){
      return txt[0].toUpperCase() +
             txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
    });
}

function split_map() {
 // сложно обработать случай "строка-пример"
  return this
    .split(/\s+/)
    .map((word) => word[0].toUpperCase() +
                 word.substr(1).toLowerCase()
    ).join(' ');
}

// String.prototype.capitalize = selected_fn;


var sample = 'просто сТРОКА-ПРИМЕР with RUSSIAN wORDS';

console.log(repl.apply(sample));
console.log(split_map.apply(sample));
```

```html
<span style="text-transform:capitalize">
  кстати, CSS решение этоГо не дЕлает
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
String.prototype.toJadenCase = function () {
  var arr = this.split(' ');
  return arr.map(function(el) {
    return el.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + el.slice(1);
  }).join(' ');
}

var str = "How can mirrors be real if our eyes aren't real";
console.dir(str.toJadenCase());
```

Елена благодарю за элегантное решения. Но javascrip и правду шире, не хотелось бы ограничивать себя только дом апи (как пояснили в комментариях). [Для примера](http://eloquentjavascript.net/) один из современных взглядов на то из чего же состоит яваскрипт:

#### Language

- **Values, Types, and Operators**
- **Program Structure**
- **Functions**
- **Data Structures: Objects and Arrays**
- **Higher-order Functions**
- **The Secret Life of Objects**
- **Bugs and Error Handling**
- **Regular Expressions**
- **Modules**

#### Browser

- **JavaScript and the Browser**
- **The Document Object Model**
- **Handling Events**
- **Drawing on Canvas**
- **HTTP**
- **Forms and Form Fields**

#### Node

- **Node.js**

Comment: стоит перенести ответы на комментарий в комментарии, уточнение лучше перенести в сам вопрос и добавить в ответ - описание решения.

Answer (score 0):

Ну если ответ Qwerty не подходит под метку, тогда так) :

```js
var str = document.getElementById("str");

str.style.textTransform = "capitalize";
```

```html
<div id="str">How can mirrors be real if our eyes aren't real</div>
```

> Ввод: "How can mirrors be real if our eyes aren't real"
>
> Вывод: "How Can Mirrors Be Real If Our Eyes Aren't Real"

Comment: Не взлетит в node.js

Comment: при чем тут еще node js?

Comment: При том, что там тоже javascript. Иными словами, для работы вашего кода он должен быть запущен в браузере, а ни в вопросе ни в метках нет ни слова о контексте выполнения js кода.

Comment: Ок. Будем считать, что минус вашему ответу я поставил просто так, из вредности

Comment: Да пожалуйста, надеюсь полегчало!!!

Comment: И, кстати, я не увидела Вашего ответа, чтобы и под node js запускалась такая важнейшая функция!
А то миносовать умеете и вредничать!

Comment: Ответ ТС вполне работает в node.js. Плодить еще один - мне лень

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko, нужно понимать что в вашем ответе используется не только и не столько javascript, сколько dom api, которое частью javascript ни разу не является и во многих местах где работает полноценный js его нет и быть не может. Я не разделяю привередливость Дмитрия, но минус тут не только "за вредность".

Answer (score 0):

```
let str = 'How can mirrors be real if our eyes aren\'t real';
let res = '';

for(i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if(i === 0) {
        res += str[i].toUpperCase();
    }else if(str[i-1] === ' ') {
        res += str[i].toUpperCase()
    }else {
        res +=str[i]
    }
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score -3):

```css
body {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
How can mirrors be real if our eyes aren't real
```

Comment: Теги под вопросом как-бы намекают...

Comment: Там же только один тег...

Comment: ... и этот тег совсем не [tag:css]

Comment: Чем непонятнее вопрос, тем рандомнее ответ :)

Comment: Минус поставил, бесполезный ответ на вопрос. Предлагаю вам @Qwertiy удалить его.