# Первые буквы каждого слова с большой буквы

Tags: javascript, while, for

Дана строка, и при помощи цикла while и for надо сделать в ней первые буквы каждого слова заглавными, я предполагаю, что начало где-то такое:

```js
let string = 'I am  the code';
for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++){
    console.log()
}
```

Comment: Копай в сторону string.toUpperCase()
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027224/how-can-i-test-if-a-letter-in-a-string-is-uppercase-or-lowercase-using-javascrip

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/579279/178988

Comment: Это какое-то академическое задание или откуда взялось условие "при помощи цикла while и for"?

Comment: Ну да, можно и так сказать

Answer (score 6):

Я просто оставлю это здесь.

```js
let string = 'I am  the code';

console.log(
string.split(/\s+/).map(word => word[0].toUpperCase() + word.substring(1)).join(' ')
);
```

Comment: Это же регулярное выражение, а надо конкретно с циклами

Comment: В исходной строке между "am" и "the" - два пробела, а в полученной строке - один. Требования убирать лишние пробелы в вопросе вроде нет. :)

Comment: @Yaant Это легко исправляется, если заменить в split регулярку на простой пробел.

Answer (score 3):

```js
function string() {
  let string = 'I am  the code';
  var splits = string.split(" ");
  var stringItog = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < splits.length; i++) {
    let Name = splits[i];
    let First = Name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
    let Leftovers = Name.substring(1, Name.length)
    stringItog += First + Leftovers + " ";
  }

  console.log(stringItog)
}
string();
```

Comment: Тут та же проблема, что и в другом ответе - результирующая строка оказалась короче, чем исходная.

Comment: при переписывании думал просто ошибка какая и убрал лишний пробел) исправил

Comment: А, я даже сразу не обратил внимание, что строка в вашем коде встречается в двух местах. Стоило бы убрать ее определение в теле функции, раз все равно вызываете функцию с параметром. :)

Answer (score 2):

```js
String.prototype.firstLetterCaps = function() {
  return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1);
}

let str = 'I am  the code'
let arr = str.split(' ')
let out = ''
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (i == arr.length - 1) {
    out += arr[i].firstLetterCaps()
  } else {
    out += arr[i].firstLetterCaps() + ' '
  }
}

console.log(out)
```